# requestAnimationFrame and setInterval animating at a different pace

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am translating two divs using `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame`. Animated using interval, the div translates at a rate of 3px per (1000/60)ms, which equates to 180px per 1000ms. At the same time, the div animated using `requestAnimationFrame` translates at a rate of 0.18px per 1ms, which equates to 180px per 1000ms.

However, they curiously aren't translating at the speed I want. Look at the example below:

```js
let interval = document.querySelector('.interval')
let raq = document.querySelector('.raq')

function startAnimation() {
  let translateValue = 0
  setInterval(() => {
    translateValue = (translateValue + 3) % 300
    interval.style.transform = `translateX(${translateValue}px)`
  }, 1000 / 60)

  let raqAnimation = (timeElapsed) => {
    let translateValue = (timeElapsed * 0.18) % 300
    raq.style.transform = `translateX(${translateValue}px)`
    window.requestAnimationFrame(raqAnimation)
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(raqAnimation)
}

window.setTimeout(startAnimation, 1000)
```

```css
.interval,
.raq {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #121212;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="interval"></div>
<div class="raq"></div>
```

Did I use `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` wrong or did I fail at the maths calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a absolutely no guarantee that your iterval will run at the requested rate so just adding some constant every callback like the code does for the setInterval case isn't going to match.

you could use `performance.now` or `Date.now` as your clock in the `setInterval` case

```js
let interval = document.querySelector('.interval')
let raq = document.querySelector('.raq')

function startAnimation() {
  setInterval(() => {
    const translateValue = (performance.now() * 0.18) % 300
    interval.style.transform = `translateX(${translateValue}px)`
  }, 1000 / 60)

  let raqAnimation = (timeElapsed) => {
    let translateValue = (timeElapsed * 0.18) % 300
    raq.style.transform = `translateX(${translateValue}px)`
    window.requestAnimationFrame(raqAnimation)
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(raqAnimation)
}

window.setTimeout(startAnimation, 1000)
```

```css
.interval,
.raq {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #121212;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="interval"></div>
<div class="raq"></div>
```

they still may not perfectly align though as (a) they are actually running at different times and so get different time values and (b) the run at different rates. They will be close though since it's effectively the same clock

Comment: So should I be using something like `Date.now()` when the animation first starts and another `Date.now()` when the `setInterval`'s callback is called to deduct the former from the latter and multiply it against the speed of translation I want?

Comment: You should not be using `setInterval` for animation. it's called request**Animation**Frame for a reason

Comment: I know. Under no circumstance will I ever bother with `setInterval` for animation. I'm just curious about what's happening behind the scenes that causes them to yield different results.

Comment: Furthermore, this is *actually the expected behaviour*. requestAnimationFrame wasn't added on a whim, nor to solve a problem that didn't exist.

Comment: They are implemented different ways. rAF gets just before the browser renders, setInterval gets called whenever the browser decides, there is no formal forumla for setInterval. One browser might use max(interval, 100), another might might use `floor((interval + 10) / 100) * 100`. Antoher might look at system load and run less. Also generally rAF doensn't run if the page is not visible. setInterval is throttled if the page is not visible.

Comment: I see! That's why my value of translation on interval does not update as frequently as specified (16.6667ms) and as a result, fall behind rAF which relies on time elapsed. I initially thought that *all* setIntervals are still called eventually, but when the browser cannot run the callback inside, it will simply "queue" the multiple intervals that failed to be called. Then, when the browser can run them, it will run all the callbacks inside all those "queued" intervals and cause a snappy animation (because translation is added not 3 at at time before repaint). I was wrong, obviously.

Comment: Oh and if you have time, I really wouldn't mind if you added the different implementation note in your comment as a further elaboration to your answer ;-)