# Jerky animation problem with requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

I am trying to animate a circle to move slowly using requestAnimationFrame(); but decreasing the speed leads to jerky movement of the circle. How can this animation be made smooth.

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

JS:

```
const circle = document.querySelector(".box");
var speed = 0 ;
function animate() {
 speed +=0.2; 
 circle.style.left = `${speed}px`

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```js
const circle = document.querySelector(".box");
var speed = 0 ;
function animate() {
 speed +=0.1; 
 circle.style.left = `${speed}px`

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: what is wrong with your animation is that you believe that a display can manage tenths of pixels

Comment: How can we fix it ?same animation with requestAnimationFrame( ) but smooth.

Comment: Wrap the inner `requestAnimationFrame` inside a `setTimeout` and change the "speed" moving to `1px` increments

Comment: we cannot hope to use requestAnimationFrame on smooth movements of a tenth of a pixel

Comment: Set interval doesn't help @Andrew ...https://codepen.io/AdnanHashmi/pen/abORzJj

Comment: Mister Jojo can't we set the duration of our animation if we are using requestAnimationFrame( )

Comment: I don't think so. you should use css animate, or css transitions

Comment: animating `translate3d` instead of `left` may yield better results with fractions of pixels. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384269/smooth-transition-when-position-is-not-an-integer/60424106#60424106

Comment: @Adnan I said `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`. I tried it with 50ms delay and it looked reasonably nice. Does that fit your needs?